# TF30177: Team Project Creation Failed

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

Answers to similar questions have not resolved this issue for me. We've recently set up TFS 2015 Express on a local server to try it out. Everything seemed to be going well until I tried to make a new team project from VS 2015. No matter which template I choose, it results in the same thing:

```
---begin Exception entry---
Time: 2016-05-18T10:24:31
Module: Work Item Tracking
Exception Message: Not Implemented (type VssServiceResponseException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.HandleResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__79.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__76`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<GetResourceLocationAsync>d__87.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<CreateRequestMessageAsync>d__69.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__65`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__64`1.MoveNext()

--- end Exception entry ---
```

and

```
---begin Exception entry---
Time: 2016-05-18T10:24:31
Module: Engine
Event Description: TF30162: Task "WITs" from Group "WorkItemTracking" failed
Exception Type: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.PcwException
Exception Message: Work item type validation failed. The operation cannot be completed.
Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WitPcwPlugin.PcwPluginComponentCreator.Execute(ProjectCreationContext ctxt, XmlNode taskXml)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.PCW.ProjectCreationEngine.TaskExecutor.PerformTask(IProjectComponentCreator componentCreator, ProjectCreationContext context, XmlNode taskXml)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.PCW.ProjectCreationEngine.RunTask(Object taskObj)
--   Inner Exception   --
Exception Message: Work item type validation failed. The operation cannot be completed. (type WitPcwFatalException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WitPcwPlugin.PcwPluginComponentCreator.WitPcwTask.WorkItemTypesTask.UploadTypeDefinition(String file, Boolean execute)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WitPcwPlugin.PcwPluginComponentCreator.WitPcwTask.WorkItemTypesTask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WitPcwPlugin.PcwPluginComponentCreator.Parse(ContextWrapper wrapper, XmlNode taskXml, Boolean fExecute)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WitPcwPlugin.PcwPluginComponentCreator.Execute(ProjectCreationContext ctxt, XmlNode taskXml)

--- end Exception entry ---
```

Am I lacking some component or feature that I need to install?

Comment: Have you tried on another client machine? Have you tried with another user account? Have you ever created a successful team project before? Has one of your users been recently added/deleted or renamed in Active Directory?

Comment: Trying it on another client under another user (that has the same permissions as my user account) with VS Community 2015 as well, they are able to create a new project.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to clean the VS cache folder if you haven't:

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache
```

If your users been recently added/deleted or renamed in Active Directory, you may need to change the SID of users with [TFSConfig Identities command](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/setup-admin/command-line/tfsconfig-cmd).

By the way, if you're using TFS 2015 Update 2 or later then you can create a team project from the web as well. You may have a try to see whether you'll get the same error:

[image]

Comment: Cleaning the cache folder produces no results (although I did not have a 5.0 folder, only 4.0 and 6.0 if that makes a difference). Also, above I posted a comment about another user being able to create a new project just fine with the same version of VS Community. Both of our user accounts were added at the same time. Lastly, the option of New Team Project is not available in TFS 2015 Express, to my understanding.

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo. The number should be 6.0 (for TFS 2015). Are you using Active Directory account? Could you confirm is your account recently added/deleted or renamed in Active Directory? Have you tried to remove your account and re-add it?

Comment: Our company does indeed use Active Directory, but my username has been in the system for months now. I'll have to get with our administrator and see about deleting it and re-adding it. Should I attempt to delete my user from TFS and re-add it as well? Also, I tried repairing both TFS and my installation of VS 2015 Community to no avail. Cache was cleared and tested both before and after repair. Still no results.

Comment: You may try run TFSConfig Identities /change /fromdomain:xxx /todomain:xxx /account:yyy /toaccount:yyy to see whether it is helpful.